# compare selected month with dates saved in database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

The Idea of my code is to get all updated rows in table that happen in specific month and year for example update happen in : May 2012 .
because of that I have 2 dropdown menus that display months and years , I want when I select the month and year , all updated row that happen in selected month and year will be presented.
is there any one can help me with the idea to solve this problem , and I'll be greatfull.
hint: the stored date in database is in the form (Y-m-d).

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 0):

Hint: dont give us hints, but tell the whole story.

Possible solution to your problem (works with php 5.3+):

```
<?php
  $startDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("first day of the month", strtotime( (int) $_POST['year']."-".(int)$_POST['month'].-"01 00:00")));
  $endDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("last day of the month", strtotime( (int) $_POST['year']."-".(int)$_POST['month'].-"01 23:59")));

  $db = ; //your PDO connection

  $q = $db->prepare("SELECT `thingstoselect` FROM `yourtable` WHERE `date` > ? && `date` < ?");
  $q->execute( array( $startDate, $endDate));

  $yourResults = $q->fetchAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you storing it as a varchar or a date?

If you are storing it as a date column, then you can compare your $year and $month variables with:

`select * from TABLE where year(datecol) > $year or (year(datecol) = $year and month(datecol) >= $month);`

If it is a substring, you will have to do some funny conversions for the greater than, but you can use a substring to find exact matches:

`select * from TABLE where substring_index(stringcol,'-',1) > $year or ( substring_index(stringcol,'-',1) = $year and substring_index(substring_index(stringcol,'-',2),'-',-1) >= $month );`

The problem is MySQL has not string split function built in.

Comment: If it's stored as a date, you can use comparisons (like @John shows) rather than running functions on your columns to extract the data.  Note that mysql can't indexes functions, so year(datecol) will do a table scan.

Comment: agreed, there are different ways to skin a cat.